# ¿Por qué Intent reconoce y propone la propia aplicación como una aplicación de correo electrónico en Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

Quiero enviar un correo electrónico cuyos datos serán recogidos en un fragmento dentro de mi aplicación.

[Según la documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Email):

> Para asegurarte de que solo una app de correo electrónico (y no otra
> app de redes sociales o mensajería de texto) maneje la intent, usa la
> acción `ACTION_SENDTO` e incluye el esquema de datos `"mailto:"`. Por
> ejemplo:

Este es el método que estoy implementando, [tomado de la propia documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Email), y haciendo lo que ellos dicen:

```
public void composeEmail(String addresses, String subject, String body) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:")); // only email apps should handle this
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, addresses);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Mi problema es que, cuando intento enviar el email, **entre las aplicaciones posibles me propone la propia aplicación donde recogí los datos**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo no quiero que me proponga la propia aplicación como posibilidad de envío, sino solamente Gmail en este caso, que es la App propia de correo electrónico.

Si yo selecciono la propia aplicación, el intent vuelve a mi pantalla inicial y si selecciono Gmail me abre la App de Gmail con los datos que pasé en el intent y todo funciona OK.

Mi pregunta es: ¿hay alguna forma de evitar que me proponga mi aplicación como posibilidad de envío, pues no es una aplicación de correo electrónico? ¿Por qué la reconoce como tal?

Answer (score 0):

Lo que preguntas era un requerimiento que tuvimos hace unas semanas, el cliente deseaba que solo una app cliente que había creado se mostrara al usar el esquema "mailto:" pero que no se mostrara la aplicación Gmail.

Como indica la documentación:

> Para asegurarte de que solo una app de correo electrónico (y no otra
> app de redes sociales o mensajería de texto) maneje la intent, usa la
> acción ACTION_SENDTO e incluye el esquema de datos "mailto:".

**Al iniciar tu `Intent`, lo que realiza el sistema operativo al detectar el uso del esquema "mailto:" es buscar que aplicaciones instaladas pueden manejar este esquema, por lo tanto se van a mostrar todas las aplicaciones soportadas y no puedes evitar no mostrar alguna**, a menos que selecciones con la opción "siempre".